# reduce the number of values being shown in a line chart of ng2-charts in angular

Tags: angular, linechart, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts to display line charts in angular. X-axis shows only few labels so that it doesn't get crowded.

But y-axis shows all the values. The graph looks like this.

[image]

Is it possible to show only those values of y for which x-axis labels are shown?

My code

```
labels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];

  chartData = [
    {
      fill: false,
      data: [21, 22, 24, 21, 21, 22, 23, 24, 23, 22, 24, 25],
      borderColor : 'black',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'black',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderColor: '#0062ff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'red',
    }
  ];
```

```
 updateChartData(){
    console.log('in update chart data')
    console.log('temp values' + this.temperatureArray)
    this.chartData1[0].data =  this.temperatureArray
    this.labels = this.timeArray
  }
```

When I update chart data, the number of labels(X-values) and y-values increase

Answer (score 0):

You can pass options to your chart in html file

```
<canvas ... [options]="lineChartOptions" [chartType]="'line'"></canvas>
```

options expects an object where you can customize scales for max values and other things

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ticks` options as suggested by @Tharzeer:

[`ticks`'s `callback`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats):

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [
    {
      ticks: {
        callback: value => value % 20 ? null : value
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

in this example all values that are dividable by 20 will be ignored. See more options [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration).

`callback`'s arguments are `value, index, values`, so you have a full control over what to be skipped.

I created a sample [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stl4cn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fng2-chart-line%2Fng2-chart-line.component.ts) with this [official demo](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#LineChart) to play with. Try to modify values in `ticks` object (you have 2 places for left and right labels)